# Selenium Data scraping issue, unproper data scrapped

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from:- https://www.canadapharmacy.com/

below are a few pages that I need to scrape:-

https://www.canadapharmacy.com/products/abilify-tablet,

https://www.canadapharmacy.com/products/accolate,

https://www.canadapharmacy.com/products/abilify-mt

I need all the information from the page. I wrote the below code:-

Using Soup:-

```
base_url = 'https://www.canadapharmacy.com'
data = []
for i in tqdm(range(len(test))):
    r = requests.get(base_url+test[i])
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
    # Scraping medicine Name
    try:
        main_name = (soup.find('h1',{"class":"mn"}).text.lstrip()).rstrip()
    except:
        main_name = None
    
    try:
        sec_name = ((soup.find('div',{"class":"product-name"}).find('h3').text.lstrip()).rstrip()).replace('\n','')
    except:
        sec_name = None
    
    try:
        generic_name = (soup.find('div',{"class":"card product generic strength equal"}).find('div').find('h3').text.lstrip()).rstrip()
    except:
        generic_name = None
        
    # Description
    
    card = ''.join([x.get_text(' ',strip=True) for x in soup.select('div.answer.expanded')])

    try:
        des = card.split('Directions')[0].replace('Description','')
    except:
        des = None
    
    try:
        drc = card.split('Directions')[1].split('Ingredients')[0]
    except:
        drc = None
        
    try:
        ingre= card.split('Directions')[1].split('Ingredients')[1].split('Cautions')[0]
    except:
        ingre = None
    
    try:
        cau=card.split('Directions')[1].split('Ingredients')[1].split('Cautions')[1].split('Side Effects')[0]
    except:
        cau = None
    try:
        se= card.split('Directions')[1].split('Ingredients')[1].split('Cautions')[1].split('Side Effects')[1]
    except: 
        se = None

    for j in soup.find('div',{"class":"answer expanded"}).find_all('h4'):
        if 'Product Code' in j.text:
            prod_code = j.text
        
    #prod_code = soup.find('div',{"class":"answer expanded"}).find_all('h4')[5].text #//div[@class='answer expanded']//h4
    
    pharma = {"primary_name":main_name,
            "secondary_name":sec_name,
            "Generic_Name":generic_name,
            'Description':des,
            'Directions':drc,
            'Ingredients':ingre,
            'Cautions':cau,
            'Side Effects':se,
            "Product_Code":prod_code}
    
    data.append(pharma)
```

Using Selenium:-

```
main_name = []
sec_name = []
generic_name = []
strength = []
quantity = []
desc = []
direc = []
ingre = []
cau = []
side_effect = []
prod_code = []

for i in tqdm(range(len(test_url))):
    card = []
    driver.get(base_url+test_url[i])
    time.sleep(1)

    try:
        main_name.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='card product brand strength equal']//h3").text)
    except:
        main_name.append(None)

    try:
        sec_name.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='card product generic strength equal']//h3").text)
    except:
        sec_name.append(None)

    try:
        generic_name.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='card product generic strength equal']//h3").text)
    except:
        generic_name.append(None)

    try:
        for i in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='product-content']//div[@class='product-select']//form"):
            strength.append(i.text)

    except:
        strength.append(None)

#     try:
#         for i in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='product-select']//form//div[@class='product-select-options'][2]"):
#             quantity.append(i.text)
#     except:
#         quantity.append(None)

    card.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='answer expanded']").text)

    try:
        desc.append(card[0].split('Directions')[0].replace('Description',''))
    except:
        desc.append(None)

    try:
        direc.append(card[0].split('Directions')[1].split('Ingredients')[0])
    except:
        direc.append(None)

    try:
        ingre.append(card[0].split('Directions')[1].split('Ingredients')[1].split('Cautions')[0])
    except:
        ingre.append(None)

    try:
        cau.append(card[0].split('Directions')[1].split('Ingredients')[1].split('Cautions')[1].split('Side Effects')[0])
    except:
        cau.append(None)
    try:
        #side_effect.append(card.split('Directions')[1].split('Ingredients')[1].split('Cautions')[1].split('Side Effects')[1])
        side_effect.append(card[0].split('Cautions')[1].split('Side Effects')[1])
    except: 
        side_effect.append(None)

    for j in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='answer expanded']//h4"):
        if 'Product Code' in j.text:
            prod_code.append(j.text)
```

I am able to scrap the data from the pages but facing an issue while scraping the Strength and quantity box. I want to write the code in such a manner so that I could scrape the data from every medicine separately and convert it data frame with columns like 2mg, 5mg, 10mg , 30 tablets, 90 tablets and shows prices.

I tried this code:-

```
medicine_name1 = []
medicine_name2 = []
strength = []
quantity = []

for i in tqdm(range(len(test_url))):
    driver.get(base_url+test_url[i])
    time.sleep(1)
    
    try:
        name1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='card product brand strength equal']//h3").text
    except:
        name1 = None
        
    try:
        name2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='card product generic strength equal']//h3").text
    except:
        name2 = None
        
    try:
        for i in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='product-select']//form//div[@class='product-select-options'][1]"):
            strength.append(i.text)
            medicine_name1.append(name1)
            medicine_name2.append(name2)
    except:
        strength.append(None)
        
    try:
        for i in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='product-select']//form//div[@class='product-select-options'][2]"):
            quantity.append(i.text)
    except:
        quantity.append(None)
```

It works fine but still, here I am getting repeated values for the medicine. Could anyone please check?

Comment: Please provide some output for your Selenium code. This output will allow others to see your issue more clearly.  Also provide some details on this line in your code `requests.get(base_url+test[i])`.  What are the `test` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** it's usually more reliable to build a list of dictionaries [rather than separate lists like you are in the selenium version.]

---

Without a sample/mockup of your desired output, I can't be sure this is the exact format you'd want it in, but I'd suggest something like this solution using requests+bs4 [on the 3 links you includes as example]

```py
# import requests
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rootUrl = 'https://www.canadapharmacy.com'
prodList = ['abilify-tablet', 'accolate', 'abilify-mt']
priceList = []
for prod in prodList:
    prodUrl = f'{rootUrl}/products/{prod}'
    print('', end=f'Scraping {prodUrl} ')
    resp = requests.get(prodUrl)
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        print(f'{resp.raise_for_status()} - failed to get {prodUrl}')
        continue
    pSoup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content)

    pNameSel = 'div.product-name > h3'
    for pv in pSoup.select(f'div > div.card.product:has({pNameSel})'):
        pName = pv.select_one(pNameSel).get_text('\n').strip().split('\n')[0] 
        pDet = {'product_endpt': prod, 'product_name': pName.strip()}

        brgen = pv.select_one('div.badge-container > div.badge')
        if brgen: pDet['brand_or_generic'] = brgen.get_text(' ').strip()
        rxReq = pv.select_one(f'{pNameSel} p.mn')
        if rxReq: pDet['rx_requirement'] = rxReq.get_text(' ').strip()

        mgSel = 'div.product-select-options'
        opSel = 'option[value]:not([value=""])'
        opSel = f'{mgSel} + {mgSel}  select[name="productsizeId"] {opSel}'
        for pvRow in pv.select(f'div.product-select-options-row:has({opSel})'):
            pvrStrength = pvRow.select_one(mgSel).get_text(' ').strip()

            pDet[pvrStrength] = ', '.join([
                pvOp.get_text(' ').strip() for pvOp in pvRow.select(opSel)
            ])                 

        pDet['source_url'] = prodUrl
        priceList.append(pDet)
    print(f' [total {len(priceList)} product prices]')
```

and then to display as table:

```py
# import pandas

pricesDf = pandas.DataFrame(priceList).set_index('product_name')
colOrder = sorted(pricesDf.columns, key=lambda c: c == 'source_url')
pricesDf = pricesDf[colOrder] # (just to push 'source_url' to the end)
```

[image: op1]

---

You could also get separate columns for each tablet-count-option, if you remove

```py
            pDet[pvrStrength] = ', '.join([
                pvOp.get_text(' ').strip() for pvOp in pvRow.select(opSel)
            ])
```

and **replace** it with this loop:

```py
            for pvoi, pvOp in enumerate(pvRow.select(opSel)):  
                pvoTxt = pvOp.get_text(' ').strip()
                tabletCt = pvoTxt.split(' - ')[0]
                pvoPrice = pvoTxt.split(' - ')[-1]
                if not tabletCt.endswith(' tablets'): 
                    tabletCt = f'[option {pvoi + 1}]'    
                    pvoPrice = pvoTxt
                
                pDet[f'{pvrStrength} - {tabletCt}'] = pvoPrice
```

| index | Abilify (Aripiprazole) | Generic Equivalent - Abilify (Aripiprazole) | Generic Equivalent - Accolate (Zafirlukast) | Abilify ODT (Aripiprazole) | Generic Equivalent - Abilify ODT (Aripiprazole) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| product_endpt | abilify-tablet | abilify-tablet | accolate | abilify-mt | abilify-mt |
| brand_or_generic | Brand | Generic | Generic | Brand | Generic |
| rx_requirement | Prescription Required | NaN | NaN | Prescription Required | NaN |
| 2mg - 30 tablets | $219.99 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2mg - 90 tablets | $526.99 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 5mg - 28 tablets | $160.99 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 5mg - 84 tablets | $459.99 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 10mg - 28 tablets | $116.99 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 10mg - 84 tablets | $162.99 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 15mg - 28 tablets | $159.99 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 15mg - 84 tablets | $198.99 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 20mg - 90 tablets | $745.99 | $67.99 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 30mg - 28 tablets | $104.99 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 30mg - 84 tablets | $289.99 | $75.99 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 1mg/ml Solution - [option 1] | 150 ml - $239.99 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2mg - 100 tablets | NaN | $98.99 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 5mg - 100 tablets | NaN | $43.99 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 10mg - 90 tablets | NaN | $38.59 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 15mg - 90 tablets | NaN | $56.59 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 10mg - 60 tablets | NaN | NaN | $109.00 | NaN | NaN |
| 20mg - 60 tablets | NaN | NaN | $109.00 | NaN | NaN |
| 10mg ODT - 84 tablets | NaN | NaN | NaN | $499.99 | NaN |
| 15mg ODT - 84 tablets | NaN | NaN | NaN | $499.99 | NaN |
| 5mg ODT - 90 tablets | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | $59.00 |
| 20mg ODT - 90 tablets | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | $89.00 |
| 30mg ODT - 150 tablets | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | $129.99 |
| source_url | https://www.canadapharmacy.com/products/abilify-tablet | https://www.canadapharmacy.com/products/abilify-tablet | https://www.canadapharmacy.com/products/accolate | https://www.canadapharmacy.com/products/abilify-mt | https://www.canadapharmacy.com/products/abilify-mt |

(I transposed the table since there were so many columns and so few rows. Table markdown can be copied from output of `print(pricesDf.T.to_markdown())`)

Comment: Thanks! I am sorry as I haven't updated the solution, but yes this is something I am looking for. Thanks for the suggestion, will try to use dictionaries rather than lists next time onwards.